# How to fire a hyperlink trigger event using Jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, eventtrigger

Anybody suggest me how to fire hyperlink click event using jquery's trigger function?

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkClickMe" Text="Click Me" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#lnkClickMe").trigger('click');

$("#lnkClickMe").click(function(){
   alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: Certain browsers do have really tight restrictions when it comes to JS-induced triggering of user events (preventing "fake" redirects et. al.). So the code might be working, yet the browser does not allow your action. Will the alert pop up when you actually click the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client side code is correct. The only caveat is that ASP.NET could mangle the id of the control and it might not be `lnkClickMe` at runtime. You could use a class selector or use the ClientID server side method to get the actual id:

```
$('#<%= lnkClickMe.ClientID %>').click(function(){
   alert('clicked');
});


$('#<%= lnkClickMe.ClientID %>').trigger('click');
```

In ASP.NET 4.0 you could [configure predictable names](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2010/07/16/all-about-client-id-mode-in-asp-net-4.aspx) by using the `ClientIDMode` setting:

```
<system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="Predictable"></pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I got the solution.My code is working properly the only difference is that i had have to write the click function prior to trigger. Now its working wine. thanks